# App Crashes on Splash Screen on Android 7 React Native

Tags: crash, react-native, splash-screen

I'm facing the splash screen issue on Android 7 and lower.
It works fine on Android 7+
but on Android 7 and lower the app crashes as soon as it is opened, without a splash screen app is working fine. Any Solutions?

I have tried using different pngs and styles and color values but still the same issue.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
SplashScreen.show(this, true);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
....
 <activity
  android:name=".SplashActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
 </activity>


  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true"
    >

  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved, basically what I did earlier was that I Placed splash_screen.png in the drawable folder which worked perfectly for Android 7+ but was causing problems for Android 7 and lower.

So I placed the same splash_screen.png in all mipmaps folders and referred to mipmaps as follows in the launch_screen.xml file.

```
android:src="@mipmap/launch_screen"
```

After that splash screen worked perfectly for all the versions. Thanks